# Microsoft Authentication Failing with NGINX Reverse Proxy on Non-Standard Port

Tags: azure, nginx, svelte

I'm currently working on an application with a frontend written in Sveltekit, and I'm using Microsoft Authentication for user logins. This application is containerized using Docker Compose, and I have an NGINX reverse proxy set up to handle requests.

I want to set up this application in our testing environment with the NGINX exposed port set to 8443 instead of the standard HTTPS port (443). However, when I try to do this, Microsoft Authentication stops working.

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8443:443"
    ...
```

Is there a limitation in Microsoft Authentication or NGINX that prevents the authentication from working on a non-standard port? If so, is there any way to get around this issue to make Microsoft Authentication work with an NGINX reverse proxy on port 8443?

Thank you in advance for your help!